# Two-way binding of an object (unknown type) to a Slider

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Slider, which is bound to an object named `MyValue`. The type of `MyValue` is unknown. In `_currentType` it is specified, whether it is an Integer or a floating number.

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
private Type _currentType;

public object MyValue
{
    get
    {
        if (_myValue != null)
            return _myValue.ToString();
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_myValue != value)
        {
            _myValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, _currentType);
            OnPropertyChanged("MyValue");
        }
    }
}
```

and the Slider XAML looks like this:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding MyValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In the above code, `OnPropertyChanged("MyValue")` does not actually update the Value of my Slider. However, when I use a `DispatcherTimer` instead, which calls `OnPropertyChanged("MyValue");` every few milliseconds, it does perfectly work.

Can anyone tell my why it doesn't work with the "direct" binding (the way I did it in the posted code)?

**UPDATE**

I don't really think the actual issue is due to conversion problems. When I use the following Timer to update each slider every 100ms, it does perfectly work.

```
private CollectionViewSource _msgListView;
private DispatcherTimer TmrDisplay;

public MyViewModel()
{
    TmrDisplay = new DispatcherTimer();
    TmrDisplay.Tick += TmrDisplay_Tick;
    TmrDisplay.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
    TmrDisplay.Start();
}

private void TmrDisplay_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MsgListView != null)
    {
        foreach (Message msg in MsgListView)
            msg.OnPropertyChangedEvent("MyValue"); // bound to the Slider
    }
}

public ListCollectionView MsgListView
{
    get
    {
        return (ListCollectionView)_msgListView.View;
    }
}
```

Since I have a huge Collection bound to a very big ListView (each item contains a Slider...), it is too slow when I use the Timer. That's why I am trying to get it work with conventional binding. However, since it works with the timer (without implementing `IValueConverter`), I don't think that's the actual issue.

Also, I have tried binding a Value Converter to the Slider in XAML, in the following way. However, it still didn't work.

```
<Slider Value="{Binding MyValue, Converter={StaticResource SliderConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I was calling the OnPropertyChanged Event from another Thread (not the UI Thread). That's why it wasn't working...

Comment: Did you check the output window for binding errors?

Comment: I just found the following binding error: `...target element is 'Slider' (Name=''); target property is 'MyValue' (type 'Double') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: DoubleConverter cannot convert from (NULL).`

Comment: Is my suggestion an answer?

Comment: wait. Sorry, the Exception posted as a comment occurs when my program is initialized (at initialization `MyValue` is NULL). So, not an answer :(

Answer (score 1):

The target and the source properties should have the same type, otherwise you need a Converter. The Framework tries to use a default one (DoubleConverter), but it is not suitable for your situation.

So try to implement and use (in the binding) your own converter:

```
public class MyValueDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return 0d;
        }

        return System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```